# Path variable to access build path in android studio in cmake

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I have an android ndk based project set up in my android studio 4.0.1. The project has two c++ modules, say, `A` and `B`, and `B` links to `A`.

I set up cmake to build A first then build B. so that updates in A is always read for B.

My question is in my CMakeLists.txt file for B, I need to tell B where to find A.
I found android studio puts the lib in some place like `AndroidStudioProjects\project_name\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libA.a`
I wonder is there a way to access this path by a variable name that comes from Android Studio? so that when I copy the module to another project I dont have to hardcode the path?

Comment: Why don't you just add it in your [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)? I find your description a bit confusing though; you say that A uses B but you build B _after_ A. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @Michael my bad, updated, and yes, target_link_libraries works, thanks!